# Confusion regarding instances

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, methods

I thought I had a decent enough grasp on methods and classes from the BNR book and now that I've reached the end of the chapter on them it notes (under 'Sending bad messages')

> What would happen if you sent the **date** class method to an **NSDate**
>   instance or the **timeIntervalSince1970** instance method to the **NSDate**
>   class?

I'm so god damn confused now, I thought NSDate was a class? Why the hell is it referred to as an instance here? Aren't instances just variables found in a class/object? And what the hell are instance methods?

Comment: Sounds like you're not really grasping this just yet. Try thinking of Classes as recipees/ blueprints. An instance is an object made from that blueprint: `NSObject *thisIsAnInstanceOfNSObject = [[NSObject alloc] init];`

Comment: I'm going to have to dumb this down but please just bare with me. So the class for example would be Cars and an object would be an instance of that class, so for example Volvo. I'm having trouble understanding how instance variables and class variables coincide though? From the documentation I've read I've gathered that it has to do with whether the method is unique to that object? Going back to the car class/example, what would be an example of a class variable vs. an instance variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instance methods are methods that can be invoked on an instance of a class and are defined with the '-' character :

```
- (void)instanceMethod;
```

A class method is a method which does not require an instance of the class and can be invoked on the class itself (defined with '+') :

```
+ (void)classMethod;
```

The question you are asked is what happens if you call an instance method on a class and vice versa (class method on an instance of a class) :

```
[NSDate timeIntervalSince1970]; // Instance method (timeIntervalSince1970) called on the class itself (NSDate)

NSDate *dateInstance = [NSDate date]; // NSDate instance defined as dateInstance;
[dateInstance date]; // class method (date) called on an instance of NSDate
```

**EDIT :**

Regarding your Cars example in the comments. If Car is a class and you want to create an instance of this class named volvo :

```
Car *volvo = [[Car alloc] init];
```

Regarding class variables, if you have a static declaration of a variable in the implementation file then yes it will be shared with all the instances (i.e. change it in one instance and it will be reflected in all other instances).

If it is declared as a member instance (i.e. non-static and declared in your class) then it will be unique per class instance.

Comment: your answer has typos and i went ahead and improved it. check your code example. class method is commented as instance method and vice versa

Comment: @staticVoidMan I appreciate your help but If I have a mistake downvote and comment or post a comment on what needs to be improved

Comment: @staticVoidMan "class method is commented as instance method and vice versa" what do you mean exactly ?

Comment: @staticVoidMan You edited the answer and had mistakes. timeIntervalSince1970 is an instance method and not a class method

Comment: `+timeIntervalSince1970` is a class method of `NSDate` but you've commented it as `Instance method (timeIntervalSince1970) called on the class itself (NSDate)`. just that. **plus** you haven't explained the difference between `[NSDate date]` and `[dateInstance date]`.

Comment: @staticVoidMan please do me a favor and look at the apple NSDate docs and you are welcome to post your answer if mine is not clear enough.

Comment: ok, my mistake. i got confused after i read your answer :P **but you can't do `[NSDate timeIntervalSince1970];`...** kindly re-examine your objective-c skills

Comment: @staticVoidMan I was making a point regarding his question not telling him what he can do and what he can't that was the whole point of the question asked!

Comment: ok, fine. i am bailing from this discussion but let me go on the record: I don't like your answer. It doesn't really answer the core question. imho

Comment: Guys come on, lets be civil... 

So I have classes, objects, and methods/variables. All classes I create have to have a parent class. An object is an instance of a class, and methods are divided into instance methods and class methods. 

Instance methods are shared by all of the instances of the class and can have different values whereas class methods can only have on value throughout the instances.

Comment: So for example if Cars was a class I created. Volvo would be the instance of a class (an object). wheelsOnCar = 4 would be a class method (since its static throughout) and colorOfCar would be an instance method because it can differ in each instance of the Cars class.

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much for the help I really do appreciate it. I'm new to this site but if there's any way I can thank you for the help just let me know!